# Find all files contained into directory named

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, find

I would like to recursively find all files contained into a directory that has name “name1” or name  “name2”

for instance:

```
structure/of/dir/name1/file1.a
structure/of/dir/name1/file2.b
structure/of/dir/name1/file3.c
structure/of/dir/name1/subfolder/file1s.a
structure/of/dir/name1/subfolder/file2s.b
structure/of/dir/name2/file1.a
structure/of/dir/name2/file2.b
structure/of/dir/name2/file3.c
structure/of/dir/name2/subfolder/file1s.a
structure/of/dir/name2/subfolder/file2s.b
structure/of/dir/name3/name1.a ←this should not show up in the result
structure/of/dir/name3/name2.a ←this should not show up in the result
```

so when I start my magic command the expected output should be this and only this:

```
structure/of/dir/name1/file1.a
structure/of/dir/name1/file2.b
structure/of/dir/name1/file3.c
structure/of/dir/name2/file1.a
structure/of/dir/name2/file2.b
structure/of/dir/name2/file3.c
```

I scripted something but it does not work because it search within the files and not only folder names:

```
for entry in $(find $SEARCH_DIR -type f | grep 'name1\|name2');
    do
      echo "FileName: $(basename $entry)"
 done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the `-regex` option, avoiding subfolders with `[^/]`:

```
~$ find . -type f -regex ".*name1/[^/]*" -o -regex ".*name2/[^/]*"
./structure/of/dir/name2/file1.a
./structure/of/dir/name2/file3.c
./structure/of/dir/name2/subfolder
./structure/of/dir/name2/file2.b
./structure/of/dir/name1/file1.a
./structure/of/dir/name1/file3.c
./structure/of/dir/name1/file2.b
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `-path` and `-prune` for this, since it's standard (unlike `-regex` which is GNU specific).

```
find . \( -path "*/name1/*" -o -path "*/name2/*" \) -prune -type f -print
```

But more importantly, never do `for file in $(find...)`. Use `find`s `-exec` or a while read loop instead, depending on what you really need to with the matching files. See [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) and [BashFAQ 20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for more on how to handle `find` safely.

Comment: yes man, the problem is that if you want to store the filenames into a variable the variable will exist only inside the while loop and it is empty as soon as you come out.

Comment: @mattobob, if you run the while loop in a subshell, yes. There are various ways around that. One way is running find in a process substitution, e.g.: `while IFS= read -rd '' file; do ...; done < <(find ... -print0)`. FAQ 20 covers this.